# Assigning values to a column based on the presence of a substring in another column of the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Alright, I have a DataFrame that contains names and values in separate columns. However I need to treat some of the values differently. Luckily the names of the values to be treated differently contain the strings 'Rate' or 'ratio' in them.

What I would like to do is create a new column, called say "Rate/Ratio?", that is assigned a value of "Yes" when one of those two strings appear in the name. Otherwise is is assigned a value of "No"

So far, I have the column created with all values assigned to "No" and would like some method to iterate row wise through the dataframe.

I believe the answer lies in some combination of pandas.loc and numpy.where but I am getting some errors I am not familiar with, mainly

```
ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
```

I have tried a bunch of different methods to work this, most recently something to the effect of :

```
appendedAggregate.loc[appendedAggregate['Rate/Ratio?'].where(appendedAggregate.loc[appendedAggregate['KPI Alias'].str.contains('Rate' or 'ratio')])] = 'Yes'
```

Here `appendedAggregate` is the DataFrame.

Comment: maybe do something like this `df['flag'] = df['name'].str.contains('Rate') | df['name'].str.contains('ratio')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.apply` to use lambda with your column.
Use `|` in `str. contains` to add `OR` operator to your words list.

`(?i)rate|ratio` for case insensitive match

Try this:

```
 df['Rate/Ratio?'] =df['name'].apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x.str.contains(r'Rate|ratio') else 'No')
```

Comment: Please, dont forget to vote for the best answers